# $p^{r+s+t}+(1-p)^{r+s+t} \geqslant [p^{r+s}+(1-p)^{r+s}]\times[p^{s+t}+(1-p)^{s+t}]$

Tags: probability, inequality

How to prove this? and is there any generalization based on some algebraic inequalities?

It seems that it's a special case of Jensen or Inequality of arithmetic and geometric means.

Set $0 \leqslant  p \leqslant 1 $ and  $r,s,t \in \mathbb{N}$

prove that:

$$p^{r+s+t}+(1-p)^{r+s+t} \geqslant [p^{r+s}+(1-p)^{r+s}]\times[p^{s+t}+(1-p)^{s+t}]$$

Comment: [+1] Very interesting, but no idea about a proof...

Comment: You have to assume (at least) that $s > 0$. Otherwise taking $s=0$ and $r=t=1$ for $p=0.5$ gives a LHS equal to 0.5, whereas the RHS is equal to 1.

Comment: @JeanMarie: The question requires  $r,s,t \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: @Martin R The most classical meaning for $\mathbb{N}$ is the set of nonnegative integers, thus $\geq 0$ integers (see (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number))

Comment: Let us assume to have a questionnaire made by three sections, the first section with $r$ questions, the second section with $s$ questions, the third section with $t$ questions. We provide random answers to each question and each answer is correct with a probability equal to $p$. There is a peculiar marking scheme: the test (or part of it, made by two sections) is passed if all the given answers are correct, *or* if none of them are. There is a test like this in May and a similar one in September (the values of $p,r,s,t$ do not change between these session).

Comment: We are stating that the probability of passing the whole test in May is greater than the probability of clearing the first two sections in May, then the last two sections in September.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio I  wanted to ask to the OP the probabilistic origin of the problem, but you have found one. I just posted a solution based on a barycentric interpretation.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Tnx. But I know the probability consideration. I want a algebraic proof.

Comment: @HannibalLecter: Jean Marie gave you a pretty interesting one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an algebraic/geometric proof.

We have to assume $s \geqslant 1$ (otherwise, the inequality is false).

Let $q=1-p$. We can assume WLOG that

$$\tag{0}p \geqslant q.$$

As all quantities involved in the inequality to be proven are $>0$, it is equivalent to establish that

$$\tag{1} p^{s}p^{t}+q^{s}q^{t} \leqslant \dfrac{p^{r+s}p^t+q^{r+s}q^t}{p^{r+s}+q^{r+s}}$$

It is sufficient to prove that

$$\tag{2} \dfrac{p^{s}p^{t}+q^{s}q^{t}}{p^s+q^s} \leqslant \dfrac{p^{r+s}p^t+q^{r+s}q^t}{p^{r+s}+q^{r+s}}$$

(because for $s \geqslant 1$, $ \ p^s+q^s \leqslant 1$. Thus $(2) \implies (1)$ ).

Setting

$$\tag{3} w_1=p^s, \ \ \ w_2=q^s, \ \ \ w'_1=p^{r+s}, \ \ \ w'_2=q^{r+s},$$

(2) can be interpreted as a relationship between barycenters (weighted means) of the **same** numbers $p^t$ and $q^t$:

$$\tag{4} \dfrac{w_1 p^{t}+w_2q^{t}}{w_1  +w_2} \leqslant  \dfrac{w'_1p^t+w'_2q^t}{w'_1+w'_2}$$

Let us recall that hypothesis (0) implies that

$$\tag{5} 0 \leqslant q^t \leqslant p^t \leqslant 1$$

Thus (4) will be established if the weights' ratios are like this:

$$\tag{6} \dfrac{w_1}{w_2} \leqslant \dfrac{w'_1}{w'_2} $$

(meaning that the barycenter is **more attracted** by $p^t$ on the RHS than on the LHS).

(6) is easy to check because:

$$ p \geqslant q \implies (\tfrac{p}{q})^s \leqslant (\tfrac{p}{q})^{r+s} $$

In plain terms, the RHS of (4) interpreted as a barycenter is on the right of the barycenter on the LHS of (4).

**Remarks:**

1) Relationship (2) is a stronger inequality than the proposed inequality.

2) The hypothesis that $r,s,t$ are integers can be relaxed: it suffices that $r>0, s \geqslant 1, t>0$ with real values.

Comment: (+1) I guess this is more or less equivalent to regarding the given inequality as a consequence of Karamata's inequality. Very nice.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio Thanks.  I will have a look at Kamarata's inequality that I don't know.

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks. But I was looking for a simple proof. it seems a little bit complicated

Comment: Complicated ? I don't think so. I  would say "unexpected"...  especialy if you haven't been in close contact with  barycenters before. Besides, can you say what is the initial probabilistic context of this inequality ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Yeah, Thanks. It was something similar to the one that Jack said.